# Gps arduino error not in sync: resp=0x86

Tags: arduino

Actually I am using arduino uno to program a gps sensor. The gps sensor that I am using is LS23060.

I got the code from the internet, I adjust few things in it, however, when I want to upload it , I get this error ;

```
Avrdude: stk500_getsync (): not in sync: resp=0x86
```

Any idea what is happening ?

Thank you in advance

```
#include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 int ledPin = 13;                  // LED test pin
 int rxPin = 0;                    // RX PIN 
 int txPin = 1;                    // TX TX
 int byteGPS=-1;
 char linea[300] = "";
 char comandoGPR[7] = "$GPRMC";
 int cont=0;
 int bien=0;
 int conta=0;
 int indices[13];
 void setup() {
   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);       // Initialize LED pin
   pinMode(rxPin, INPUT);
   pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT);
   Serial.begin(4800);
   for (int i=0;i<300;i++){       // Initialize a buffer for received data
     linea[i]=' ';
   }   
 }

 void loop() {
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
   byteGPS=Serial.read();         // Read a byte of the serial port
   if (byteGPS == -1) {           // See if the port is empty yet
     delay(100); 
   } else {
     // note: there is a potential buffer overflow here!
     linea[conta]=byteGPS;        // If there is serial port data, it is put in the buffer
     conta++;                      
     Serial.write(byteGPS); 
     if (byteGPS==13){            // If the received byte is = to 13, end of transmission
       // note: the actual end of transmission is <CR><LF> (i.e. 0x13 0x10)
       digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); 
       cont=0;
       bien=0;
       // The following for loop starts at 1, because his code is clowny and the first byte is the <LF> (0x10) from the previous transmission.
       for (int i=1;i<7;i++){     // Verifies if the received command starts with $GPR
         if (linea[i]==comandoGPR[i-1]){
           bien++;
         }
       }
       if(bien==6){               // If yes, continue and process the data
         for (int i=0;i<300;i++){
           if (linea[i]==','){    // check for the position of the  "," separator
             // note: again, there is a potential buffer overflow here!
             indices[cont]=i;
             cont++;
           }
           if (linea[i]=='*'){    // ... and the "*"
             indices[12]=i;
             cont++;
           }
         }
         Serial.println("");      // ... and write to the serial port
         Serial.println("");
         Serial.println("---------------");
         for (int i=0;i<12;i++){
           switch(i){
             case 0 :Serial.print("Time in UTC (HhMmSs): ");break;
             case 1 :Serial.print("Status (A=OK,V=KO): ");break;
             case 2 :Serial.print("Latitude: ");break;
             case 3 :Serial.print("Direction (N/S): ");break;
             case 4 :Serial.print("Longitude: ");break;
             case 5 :Serial.print("Direction (E/W): ");break;
             case 6 :Serial.print("Velocity in knots: ");break;
             case 7 :Serial.print("Heading in degrees: ");break;
             case 8 :Serial.print("Date UTC (DdMmAa): ");break;
             case 9 :Serial.print("Magnetic degrees: ");break;
             case 10 :Serial.print("(E/W): ");break;
             case 11 :Serial.print("Mode: ");break;
             case 12 :Serial.print("Checksum: ");break;
           }
           for (int j=indices[i];j<(indices[i+1]-1);j++){
             Serial.print(linea[j+1]); 
           }
           Serial.println("");
         }
         Serial.println("---------------");
       }
       conta=0;                    // Reset the buffer
       for (int i=0;i<300;i++){    //  
         linea[i]=' ';             
       }                 
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I alreaxybposted the code in the "answers". Could you please check it?

Comment: with the computer switched on try holding down the reset button whilst plugging the USB cable into the Arduino.

Comment: It does not work 

Comment: Where have you been all week? I had thought everything was ok now :) Well, try this link - someone else with 0x86 error code http://www.yuriystoys.com/2012/09/arduino-bluetooth-module-wireless-dro.html

Comment: Thank you so much btw. The problem was about the driveres . Now we are using mac os instead of windows os . Thank you again so much 

Comment: Glad to hear it's working now. You should add the answer and accept it. Others may benefit from your question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So, actually you have to check if the derives are chosen in a proper way, or you can switch to mac . This error will not be there .